# LINQ - First occurrence in a group

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have users recordset and i want to get a list of the first occurrence of a each row where duplicate usrEmployeeID field values.

```
var uniqueuser = 
    from ur in Users 
    group ur by ur.UsrEmployeeID into g 
    select new User { 
        g.Select(x => x).First()
    };
```

This does not work??

Cannot initialize object of type 'User' with a collection initializer

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `First()` is a `User`. You don't have to use `new`.

```
var uniqueuser = from ur in Users 
                 group ur by ur.UsrEmployeeID into g
                 select g.First();
```

Comment: I changed my answer. You don't have to create a new user

Comment: Cannot execute text selection: Invalid expression term '{'

; expected